# Cache entry is not removed from cache store (SingleFileCacheStore)

Tags: java, spring, caching, infinispan

I am using `singleFileCacheStore`. I have set `maxEntries` to 0 with `passivation` disabled

```
<persistence passivation="false" >  
        <singleFile fetchPersistentState="true" preload="true"   
                     ignoreModifications="false"  
                     purgeOnStartup="false" maxEntries="0" >  
         </singleFile>  
</persistence>
```

In my application I am firing `cache.remove(key)`, but I still see entries in underlying file.

Any clue, whats wrong? Do I need to call any extra API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space for an entry is just marked and it will reused by new or updated entries. So you will always see the old data, until something new is written.

When a purge is processed the file itself will be truncated / shrinked. The `SingleFileCacheStore` implementation is very simple, so this only happens if there is free space at the end of the file. There is no compaction if you have free space somewhere in the middle of the file. That is not perfect, but quite good enough, since there is usually always fluctuation in the entries within a cache. But it means, that if you force a purge the file may not be truncated, even when there is free space.

See under eviction in the [documentation](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_eviction) how you control a purge. Essentially that is:

> The purpose of the EvictionManager is to drive the eviction/expiration
>   thread which periodically purges items from the DataContainer. If the
>   eviction thread is disabled (wakeupInterval set to -1) eviction can be
>   kicked off manually using EvictionManager.processEviction(), for
>   example from another maintenance thread that may run periodically in
>   your application.